# Elegant way of creating an array full of one number in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I know that to get 10 `0`'s, one can do

```
A = zeros(10, 1);
```

To get 10 `1`'s, one can do

```
A = ones(10, 1);
```

What about any arbitrary number? Say, I want 10 `3`'s. I have come up with a way of doing it.

```
A = linspace(3, 3, 10);
```

Is this satisfactory? Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I always use the following: `A = 3 * ones(10, 1):`

Comment: @gire Huh! Right. I am too dumb to think of this!

Comment: I was also thinking of `repmat` as @LuisMendo. Would be interesting, which one is faster (`repmat`, `ones()*...` or `zeros()+...`).

Comment: Good question. Never thinking about it my usual approach was ``3*ones(10,1)``. There are a lot of different ways possible though, as the answers suggest. It would be nice if someone with some spare time would do a speed test for different vector-sizes. My gut feeling is that @LuisMendo comment on Dennis' answer looks promising.

Comment: If you are playing [code-golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf): `A(1:10)=3`, assuming there's no variable named `A` declared before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some alternatives:

- Using [`repmat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

  ```
  A = repmat(3, [5 7]); %// 5x7 matrix filled with the value 3
  ```
- Using indexing:

  ```
  A(1:m, 1:n) = x;
  ```

Following is a **timing comparison** between all proposed approaches. As you can see, **[@Dennis' solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26714166/2586922) are the fastest** (at least on my system).

Functions:

```
function y = f1(x,m,n) %// Dennis' "ones"
y = x*ones(m,n);

function y = f2(x,m,n) %// Dennis' "zeros"
y = x+zeros(m,n);

function y = f3(x,m,n) %// Luis' "repmat"
y = repmat(x,[m n]);

function y = f4(x,m,n) %// Luis' "dirty"
y(m,n) = 0;
y(:) = x;

function y = f5(x,m,n) %// Luis' "indexing"
y(1:m,1:n) = x;

function y = f6(x,m,n) %// Divakar's "matrix porod"
y = x*ones(m,1)*ones(1,n);
```

Benchmarking script for square arrays:

```
x = 3;
sizes = round(logspace(1,3.7,10)); %// max limited by computer memory
for s = 1:numel(sizes)
    n = sizes(s);
    m = sizes(s);
    time_f1(s) = timeit(@() f1(x,m,n));
    time_f2(s) = timeit(@() f2(x,m,n));
    time_f3(s) = timeit(@() f3(x,m,n));
    time_f4(s) = timeit(@() f4(x,m,n));
    time_f5(s) = timeit(@() f5(x,m,n));
    time_f6(s) = timeit(@() f6(x,m,n));
end
loglog(sizes, time_f1, 'r.-');
hold on
loglog(sizes, time_f2, 'g.:');
loglog(sizes, time_f3, 'b.-');
loglog(sizes, time_f4, 'm.-');
loglog(sizes, time_f5, 'c.:');
loglog(sizes, time_f6, 'k.:');
xlabel('Array size')
ylabel('Time')
legend('ones', 'zeros', 'repmat', 'dirty', 'indexing', 'matrix prod')
```

For column arrays: just change the following lines:

```
sizes = round(logspace(1,3.7,10)).^2; %// max limited by computer memory
n = 1;
m = sizes(s);
```

For row arrays:

```
sizes = round(logspace(1,3.7,10)).^2; %// max limited by computer memory
n = sizes(s);
m = 1;
```

Results for a dual-core CPU, 2-GB RAM, Windows Vista, Matlab R2010b:

1. Square arrays;
2. Column arrays;
3. Row arrays.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting results for the small arrays.

Comment: x and y labels? Maybe add that *dirty* `B(10,1)=0` approach?

Comment: I've updated the benchmarking as suggested by @Nras and Divakar

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the name, I couldn't find any, and that one is perfect! :-)

Comment: haha no! Well I use that trick all the time and calling it "dirty" isn't preferred by me! But I guess its still better than being called "dangerous" :)

Comment: `directly with indexing` seemed a bit slower than dirty one at my end.

Comment: Added my own [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26715771/3293881). Could add that into benchmarks? Sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: +1, nice comparison. Maybe add a conclusion? Your introduction seems to recommend using `repmat`, but from the graphs it appears that `ones` and `zeros` are always the fastest ...

Comment: Thank you on that! Not that I was expecting matrix-mult to excel, but it could be an alternative approach.

Comment: @Divar Yes, it's not very intuitive how all these perform. I also expected the dirty approach to be the winner, as it involves no operations and no more memory allocation than the others...

Comment: Yeah, I am surprised on that too, "dirty" one had to be good with runtime.

Answer (score 7):

There are two basic ways to do this:

```
A = ones(10,1)*3
B = zeros(10,1)+3
```

The first one is most commonly used in examples, yet if I am not mistaken, the second one performs slightly better. All in all it is just a matter of taste.

Of course, if you have an existing matrix, there is another simple way:

```
C = zeros(10,1)
C(:) = 3;
```

And for completeness, the repmat solution as suggested by @Luis is also fine.

Comment: I never thought about it, but you are right. Using the second method will be slightly faster because of cpu pipelining, which is not available (to my best knowledge) in the case of a multiplication. Besides, multiplication takes more cpu cycles than the addition.

Comment: +1 You could also use `B(10,1)=0; B=B+3;` instead of `B = zeros(10,1)+3`. It may be faster

Comment: @LuisMendo That only works if there is no `B`, so would require a clear to be safe.

Comment: @LuisMendo maybe faster but also more dangerous if a variable B already exists, this could very well throw an error.

Comment: @Nras @Dennis Agreed. `clear B` first. Also, this could be faster as it avoids arithmetical operations: `B(10,1)=0; B(:)=3;`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, a `matrix multiplication` (which is supposed to be pretty fast on MATLAB) based method could be also be suggested for `2D` or `multidimensional array` assignment work.

Thus, assuming `m` as `rows`, `n` as `columns` and `x` as the value to be assigned for all elements, the code would be -

```
y = x*ones(m,1)*ones(1,n);
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) out! Rock star!

Comment: @chappjc haha yeah I saw that, not much to say really .. s**t happens I guess! ;)